# How to automatically stop logstash process instance after its read the doc

Tags: logstash

I want to ask that, below is my code. With the below code logstash reads the file until its end. Then it is stops reading but process is still alive. I want that process stops when it finishes the reading. How can i do this ?

```
file {
        path => "directory/*.log"
        start_position => "beginning"
        mode => "read"
 
}
```

Thanks for answering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using the **stdin input** plugin instead of **file input**, and passing the file as input in the command for starting logstash.
e.g.

```
bin/logstash -f readFileFromStdin.conf < /path_to_file/test.log
```

For multiple files you could do

```
bin/logstash -f readFileFromStdin.conf < cat /path_to_file/*.log
```

or

```
cat /path_to_file/*.log > /tmp/myLogs
bin/logstash -f readFileFromStdin.conf < /tmp/myLogs
```

Comment: For one file that works. But  I want all the log files inside of the directory. "directory/*.log" . For this I can't put their names manualy ? Could you give an example for this ? If yes. I will accept the answer. Thank you

Comment: Edited the answer for multiple files. Hope it helps.